# Extracting data to different tabs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a spreadsheet that I will be importing data into from multiple sources and I want to be able to extract the data to other tabs based on the descriptions. For example, I want to pull all of the rows that say "Credit Canadian Deposit Settlement" in Column B and put them into a separate tab so that I can work with them.

Since I have to do this with a large amount of data each week I would like to have as much of it as possible automated so that I can just import that data and then start working with it without too much manipulation. I would eventually like to have a tab for each different description.

[spreadsheet sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R90y.png)

Comment: how do you import the data into this workbook? If you are using an external datasource could you setup a query that pulls the correct data into each tab? or is there a problem with that approach?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't possible as the data is being taken from a PDF

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with Power Query:

https://www.excelcampus.com/powerquery/power-query-overview/

Otherwise you it would be better to write a macro. Start by recording a macro using the following steps:

1. Select cell A1
2. Insert a table
3. Filter for one of the descriptions
4. Press ctrl-A to select entire range
5. Copy
6. Paste to the target spreadsheet

Then review and update the code:

Replace any references to a fixed range with a general range, such as:

```
Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

Then you can also insert a loop to run through each possible value. Search/ask for help on writing loops in VBA for further info.